# CUDA Error on cudaBindTexture2D

Tags: cuda

I've got a problem with cudaBindTexture2D. Following code I created to reproduce this issue, but this one... works:

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// This will output the proper CUDA error strings in the event that a CUDA host call returns an error
#define checkCudaErrors(err)  __checkCudaErrors (err, __FILE__, __LINE__)

inline void __checkCudaErrors(cudaError err, const char *file, const int line )
{
    if(cudaSuccess != err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s(%i) : CUDA Runtime API error %d: %s.\n",file, line, (int)err, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
        exit(-1);        
    }
}

texture<float,2> myTex;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float* input;
    input = new float[656 * 480];
    for(int i = 0; i < 656*480; ++i)
    {
        input[i] = i;
    }
    float* inputDevice;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc ((void**)&inputDevice, 656 * 480 * sizeof(float) ));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(inputDevice, input, 656 * 480 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();

    checkCudaErrors(cudaBindTexture2D(0, myTex, inputDevice, desc, 656, 480, sizeof(float) * 656));

    cudaUnbindTexture(myTex);
    cudaFree(inputDevice);

    return 0;
}
```

But in my real project, the presumably same code ain't working.

```
texture<float,2> texInput;

/* a lot of code here, but nothing with texInput */

    void CUDAConv::DoConvolution(float* input, float* kernel1D, float* resultMap, unsigned char* rMap, unsigned char* orientMap, int width, int height, int kernelSize)
    {
        int fDim = (int)(floor((sqrt((float)(width * width + height * height)) / 2 + 0.5f)));
        //Lock* locks = new Lock[width * height];
        int dim = fDim * 2 + 1;
        devWidth = width;
        devHeight = height;

        // allocate memory on GPU for the summing images
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&inputDevice, width * height * sizeof(float)));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(inputDevice, input, width * height * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

        cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&kernel1DDevice, kernelSize));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaBindTexture2D(0, texInput, inputDevice, desc, width, height, sizeof(float) * width));

        checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&radiusDevice, width * height));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&orientationDevice, width * height));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&resultDevice, width * height * sizeof(float)));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(resultDevice, 0x00, width * height * sizeof(float)));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(kernel1DDevice, kernel1D, kernelSize * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        for(int i = 0; i < angles; ++i)
        {
            checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&sumUpImage[i], angles * width * height * sizeof(float)));
            checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(&sumUpImage[i], 0x00, width * height * angles * sizeof(float)));
            checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void**)&rotationImage[i], angles * dim * dim * sizeof(float)));
            checkCudaErrors(cudaMemset(&rotationImage[i], 0x00, dim * dim * angles * sizeof(float)));
        }

        // do all convolution calculations in the Convolution function
        convolution <<<1, angles>>> (/*locks, */inputDevice, kernel1DDevice, rotationImage, sumUpImage, resultDevice, radiusDevice, orientationDevice, devWidth, devHeight, angles);

        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(resultMap, resultDevice, width * height * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

        // free memory allocated on the GPU
        for(int i = 0; i < angles; ++i)
        {
            checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(sumUpImage[i]));
        }

        //free(locks);
        cudaUnbindTexture(texInput);
        cudaFree(inputDevice);
        cudaFree(kernel1DDevice);
        cudaFree(radiusDevice);
        cudaFree(orientationDevice);
        cudaFree(resultDevice);
    }
```

The error I would get consequently on cudaBindTexture2D is:

CUDA_Conv.cu(203) : CUDA Runtime API error 18: invalid texture reference.

When debugging the texInput looks just like myTex, and I can't figure out what's happening here.

Using CUDA4.2 with VS2010.

Comment: Do you get the error the first time DoConvolution is run?

Comment: Are all the compile settings the same between the two projects? Same GPU sm/arch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the comments, I used a sm that my GPU wasn't compatible to, strangely enough it wouldn't throw the error on cudaMalloc, but only on cudaBindTexture, but setting both the same sm / arch, and they behaved the same.

Thanks Roger!