# CUDA Error on cudaBindTexture

Tags: cuda

I have exactly the same problem as described in the post:
[CUDA Error on cudaBindTexture2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354020/cuda-error-on-cudabindtexture2d)

I even have the following error:

> error 18: invalid texture reference." and also experienced "wouldn't
>   throw the error on cudaMalloc, but only on cudaBindTexture

Unfortunately, the poster (Anton Roth) answered his own question in a manner that was a bit too cryptic for someone such as myself who is just starting out with CUDA:

> The answer was in the comments, I used a sm that my GPU wasn't
>   compatible to.

The "not compatible with GPU" makes sense since the sample program [FluidsGL](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/#fluids--opengl-version-) (called "Fluids (OpenGL Version)" in NVIDIA CUDA Samples Browser) fails on my laptop, but works fine on my desktop at work. Unfortunately, I still don't know what "in the comments" was referring it, or how to even check for GPU SM compatibilities.

Here is the code that seems to be causing the issue:

```cpp
#define DIM 512
```

In `main`:

```cpp
setupTexture(DIM, DIM);
bindTexture();
```

In `fluidsGL_kernels.cu`:

```cpp
texture<float2, 2> texref;
static cudaArray *array = NULL;

void setupTexture(int x, int y)
{
    // Wrap mode appears to be the new default
    texref.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
    cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float2>();

    cudaMallocArray(&array, &desc, y, x);
    getLastCudaError("cudaMalloc failed");
}

void bindTexture(void)
{
    cudaBindTextureToArray(texref, array);//this function itself doesn't throw the error but error 18 is caught by the function below
    getLastCudaError("cudaBindTexture failed");
}
```

#### Hardware information

Here is the output of `deviceQuery`:

```
Device 0: "GeForce 9800M GS"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.0 / 5.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.1
  Total amount of global memory:                 1024 MBytes (1073741824 bytes)
  ( 8) Multiprocessors x (  8) CUDA Cores/MP:    64 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1325 MHz (1.32 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             799 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)             1D=(8192), 2D=(65536,32768), 3D
=(2048,2048,2048)
  Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers        1D=(8192) x 512, 2D=(8192,8192)
 x 512
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       16384 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 8192
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  768
  Maximum number of threads per block:           512
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    512 x 512 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     65535 x 65535 x 1
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             256 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  CUDA Device Driver Mode (TCC or WDDM):         WDDM (Windows Display Driver Mo
del)
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      No
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           8 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simu
ltaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 5.0, CUDA Runtime Versi
on = 5.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce 9800M GS
```

I know my GPU is kind of old, but it still runs most of the examples pretty well.

Comment: You have a CC 1.1 GPU (cf. this line `CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number`). The main question is: how are you compiling your code? Could you paste the command that you use? Are you using `-gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11`? Also, [fluidsGL](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#fluids--opengl-version-) should run fine on your hardware since the minimum SM version is 1.0 apparently.

Comment: It actually compiles fine(I'm using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 sample project without modification). The precompiled executable gave the same error as when I compile & debug on the laptop, but runs fine on the desktop.

Comment: Something similar appears in slightly different form twice in a row:
 -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\"

Comment: You will not see any error during compilation, only during execution. If you read nvcc's help (`nvcc --help`), you will see that `-code` is used to *specify the names of nVidia gpus to generate code for*, and `-arch` is used to *specify the name of the class of nVidia GPU architectures for which the cuda input files must be compiled*. If you do not set a proper architecture, errors may happen when running the code on an inadequate GPU. If you only compile for `compute/sm_20` and `compute/sm_30`, your code will fail on your GPU (hence my first comment).

Comment: Shortened:
"...\5_Simulations\fluidsGLfromwork>"...\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "...Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"  -I"./" -I"../../common/inc" -I"./" -I"../../common/inc" -I"...\CUDA\v5.0\include" -I"...\CUDA\v5.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir "Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile  -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN32 -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MTd  " -o "Win32/Debug/fluidsGL_kernels.cu.obj" "...\fluidsGL_kernels.cu"

Comment: You should consider using [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for that kind of copy/paste on Stack Overflow. As you can see, you are generating code for CC 2.0/3.0 devices, while using a CC 1.1 device.

Comment: It worked! In visual studio (btw, you need VS professional or it doesn't work at all) I went to configuration properties->CUDA C/C++ -> Device -> Code Generation, and added "compute_11,code=sm_11". Then did the same after r-clicking on fluidsGL_kernels.cu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your code for the proper architecture (as explained in the post you linked).

Since you have a CC 1.1 device, use the following nvcc compilation options:

```
-gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11
```

The default Visual Studio project or Makefile may not compile for the proper architectures, so always make sure that it does.

For Visual Studio, refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14413360/1043187

For a Makefile, it depends. The CUDA SDK samples often have a `GENCODE_FLAGS` variable that you can modify.